# Arraying two array rows and display only distinct values

Tags: sql, arrays, aggregate-functions, presto

I want to aggregate two array rows. For example, in the table below, colour column already shows the values in array format.

| id | colour |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [[Red,Blue,Yellow]] |
| 2 | [[Green]] |
| 1 | [[White,Blue]] |
| 2 | [[Green,Black]] |

By aggregating on id and distinct-selecting the colour column, I want to create a result like below.

| id | colour |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [[Red,Blue,Yellow,White]] |
| 2 | [[Green,Black]] |

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Wich DB Product are you using?

Comment: It's Amazon Athena

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presto has lots of array functions. We can try:

```
select id, array_distinct(flatten(array_agg(colour))) as colours
from mytable
group by id
```

This assumes that each array contains a list of scalars, so something like: `[Red,Blue,Yellow]` - not a one element sub-array (as shown in your sample data like `[[Red,Blue,Yellow]]`).